# Performance issues in MySQL SELECT queries?

Tags: mysql

In one of the Facebook groups someone asked a question:

Suppose we have 2 queries.

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE video_id='45f54' AND video_type='youtube';

SELECT * FROM video WHERE video_type='youtube' AND video_id='45f54'
```

`video_id` is a indexed field.

Are there any difference between performance of these two queries?

Someone answered putting indexed field just after `WHERE` clause is faster...., but why? Aren't both the same?

Comment: Hey mate you can find a good explanation for your question here:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252279/mysql-indices-and-order

But it is called the most left index. It how the parser in MYSQL works. Always try to keep the columns in your WHERE clause matching your indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming table `video` is identical then those 2 queries are effectively identical as the MySQL optimiser will handle the WHERE criteria internally.  Here are a couple of links to similar questions

- [Does the order of columns in a query matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582331/does-the-order-of-columns-in-a-query-matter)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/in-mysql-does-the-order-of-the-columns-in-a-where-clause-affect-query-performan

For optimisations, you may wish to consider the following (if not already done)

- Change video_type to be ENUM(), or even a seperate table which links via an INTEGER
- Index on (video_type,video_id) after doing the change to video_type.
- Limit the length of video_id, i.e. CHAR(5) if they are ALWAYS 5 chars long

Personally I'd make a new table "video_types" (videotypeID SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, videotype VARCHAR).  This would allow the search in video to be far more optimal potentially, though it depends on the data heavily still.

Comment: As far as I know, yes, identical.  Here's another question over on one of the other sites with same answer, http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/in-mysql-does-the-order-of-the-columns-in-a-where-clause-affect-query-performan and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582331/does-the-order-of-columns-in-a-query-matter